# Odd conversion behavior in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Here is a minimal example of some bizarre behavior I'm seeing with Amazon Redshift.  Both of these queries

```
select 0.010691::DECIMAL(20,4);
select ('0.010691'::varchar(255))::DECIMAL(20,4);
```

return `0.0107`, which is what I would expect.  But

```
create table test (
  "val" varchar(255)
);
insert into test values ('0.010691');
select val::DECIMAL(20, 4) from test;
```

returns `0.0106`, i.e., it truncates before converting instead of converting, then rounding.  Is this expected behavior?  Why are these different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is expected behavior.  In [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html#r_Numeric_types201-decimal-or-numeric-type) documentation page, there is the line, "However, results of explicit casts of values selected from tables are not rounded."  So, a feature, not a bug.